# How to get elements from simple array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I need to get values of my enum, so I am using following command:

```
Array a = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Typ));
```

However, typical expression
     a[x] 
does not work, why?

Thanks

Comment: What is "does not work"? Also why do you access specific elements by arbitrary indices instead of using the names of each enum value?

Comment: I cannot take the elmement like string = a[1]. Just the [] notation does not work

Comment: Yes, but what is "does not work"? How does it not work? What error does it give?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on OPs comments, he might not actually be interested in the *values* of the `Enum`, but instead of the *names*. The distinction can easily be confusing to beginners. **Tip:** When you ask questions involving an error (i.e. "does not work, why?"), then including the error message often helps.

If you are looking for the names in the `Enum`, try:

```
string[] names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Typ));
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, because `Enum.GetValues` is not generic.

If you write:

```
var a = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Typ));
Console.WriteLine(a.GetType());
```

You'll get: "Namespace.Typ[]". But because method is not generic, compiler can't change returning type basing on supplied type, so the method returns `System.Array` which is base type for arrays and you have to use type casts to downcast it to expected type, for example:

```
Typ[] a = (Typ[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Typ));
```

Answer (score 2):

The proper way in my opinion to do it is:

```
Array a = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Typ));
```

and then retrieve elements at positions by:

```
a.GetValue(elementsIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following code to handle emums when converting a custom classes for DB SP params, works all the time.

```
    public static object ParamValue<T>(Enum value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return System.DBNull.Value;
        else
            return (T)Enum.Parse(value.GetType(), value.ToString());
    }
```